# SQL to retrieve username and password from 3 tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, where-clause

I have to retrieve username and password from 3 SQL Server tables (user1, user2, admin, with username and password in each table) with no foreign keys.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from user1 UNION select * from user2 
union select * from admin where username = @username and password = @password", con);
```

I get an error which says:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

Comment: You are close. You just need to put that WHERE at the end of each SELECT statement (Repeated 3 times for each SELECT).

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: there's an error which says "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists"

Comment: Why have 3 tables to store the same information?  And never, ever store passwords as plaintext - salt and hash them.  Always

Comment: Also, `password` and `username` are reserved in sql, use `[password]` and `[username]`; put brackets `[ ]` around column names...

Comment: This is utterly misguided; passwords [must be stored securely](https://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs), not in rows like public information. This is a very difficult thing to do correctly, fortunately most APIs have ways of authenticating securely already included. Use them, of all things to try to invent yourself, security is the worst.

Comment: `must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists`  "Select *" won't work if the tables don't have the same number of columns.  You would have to specify the columns for each query in the union.  Very unclear why you would store user information in three different tables.

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM (select username, password from user1 UNION select username, password from user2 
    union select username, password from admin) t1 WHERE username = @username and password = @password", con);
```